# I am having issue a issue understanding "scaling transform coordinates". Need Assistance

Tags: ios, core-graphics

> **Using a scaling transform to negate the y-coordinate alters some conventions in Quartz drawing**. For example, if you call
>   **CGContextDrawImage** to draw an image into the context, the image is
>   modified by the transform when it is drawn into the destination.
>   Similarly, path drawing routines accept parameters that specify
>   whether an arc is drawn in a clockwise or counterclockwise direction
>   in the default coordinate system. If a coordinate system is modified,
>   the result is also modified, as if the image were reflected in a
>   mirror. In Figure 1-5, **passing the same parameters into Quartz results
>   in a clockwise arc in the default coordinate system and a
>   counterclockwise arc after the y-coordinate is negated by the
>   transform.**

this is from [apple quartz2d guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-TPXREF101) regarding coordinate system.

What do they mean by this first line? `Using a scaling transform to negate the y-coordinate alters some conventions in Quartz drawing.`

and in second line they have given `thecgcontextdrawimage` example, yes its true uikit automatically modifies the coordinates from lower left to upper left, so whats the point here?

and also didn't understand the last point of this, `passing the same parameters into Quartz results in a clockwise arc in the default coordinate system and a counterclockwise arc after the y-coordinate is negated by the transform.`

Thanks in advance, Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just draw attention to the fact that using a scaling transform with a negative coordinate, y in the example, creates a mirror effect. It might not be obvoius, but when looking in a mirror, the direction of the axes change. In the example they are talking about the y axys which results in reversing the notion of up and down. If you think carefully to the mirror analogy, or just pick a mirror and try :), you can imagine/see that an arc drawn clockwise will look in the mirror as drawn counter-clockwise.

Please alos note that this scaling transform just reverses the axes (up-down), it has no effect on the origin (point considered as 0,0 ) at all. This is why for a complete mirror effect you also do a translation, enought to move the origin from upper-left to lower-right corner.